# String matching exception ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am doing a simple string matching in C# console application and I want get this exception:
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

followed by extra information: *Index and length must refer to a location within the string.*

I am not sure how to interpret this..

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var b = "bananas";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
        {
            var current = b.Substring(i, j);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", b.Contains(current), current);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

All I am interested in is the cause of the error and a workaround/solution - i.e. I lack the the proper understanding obviously.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error should be self-explanatory. The parameters you're passing to `b.Substring` do not describe a valid substring in the string `b`.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense.you are getting substring from a string then checking if the string contains the substring.wouldn't it be always **true**?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, instead of just hitting the down vote button. Somehow that is not that self-explanatory to me, but your description helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `Length`, so the parameters you're passing to `Substring` are making it fail.

Here's the fixed line you need:

```
for (int j = 0; j < b.Length - i; j++)
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/4Je2MD

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. It's now clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't give the same exception and it works perfectly and provides the intended result!

Comment: @Selman22 This gives `System Error 500`, which is a HTTP error code (internal server error). The dotnetfiddle service seems down. Check the ideone link.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski sorry I read it wrong. it was b.Length - i not b.Length - 1

Comment: No problem, I can totally understand that confusion ;)